# Paypal: Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Each time I try to get info from a subscription, I get the insufficient permissions error.

I get the token from the client id and secret of the same account that I'm trying to get the info.
This is the response of the following code:

```
function getAccessToken($clientId, $secret)
{

    $url = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';

    $ch = curl_init();

    $postData = [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId . ":" . $secret);

    $headers = [];
    $headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
    $headers[] = "Accept-Language: en_US";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    if (!isset($result['access_token'])) {
        print_r($result);
        return false;
    }

    print_r($result);
    return $result['access_token'];
}
```

Response:

```
Array
(
    [scope] => https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-buyer https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalhere openid https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund https://uri.paypal.com/services/identity/activities https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://uri.paypal.com/services/reporting/search/read https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/refund https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/.*/refund
    [access_token] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [app_id] => APP-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx
    [expires_in] => 32400
    [nonce] => 2019-06-27T09:09:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
)
```

This is how I try to get the info from the subscription:

```
$url = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-XXXXXXX';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $headers = [];
    $headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer $token";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    print_r(json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true));
```

And this is the response:

```
Array
(
    [name] => NOT_AUTHORIZED
    [message] => Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.
    [debug_id] => 806a79b586a3b
    [details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [issue] => PERMISSION_DENIED
                    [description] => You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource.
                )

        )

    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#FORBIDDEN
                    [rel] => information_link
                    [method] => GET
                )

        )

)
```

In the "My Account" section of the developer dashboard, I have everything enable for live.

Any idea?

Comment: In my woring app, second CURL also has `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');` and slighly different headers: `$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';`.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio, thanks, but it didn't work. I get the same error. I think it's sometihng related to granting permissions in some place, or calling the token in a different way.

Comment: Just for reference, here are both curls I make in my app (1 for token, the other to get order details), `'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';` might make the difference: https://pastebin.com/0G4NynRz

Comment: I use your code directly, adapting the PAYPAL_ORDER_API to the subscription url and got the same result.

Comment: damn, at this point I have no idea why it returns forbidden. At least, token generation is fine

Comment: may I know if you are getting subscriptions info from business side or personal (customer) side?

Comment: Business side. My feeling is that because I'm creating the subscriptions from the website form, they aren't available from the API. I also have a ticket with PayPal, but their support is horrible.